# What is the best way to track success/failure events in celery task queue?

Tags: python, celery

What is the best way to track success/failure events in celery task queue?

Comment: What way have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

have you seen [Flower](http://flower.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) ?

from celery docs:

> Flower is a real-time web based monitor and administration tool for
>   Celery. It is under active development, but is already an essential
>   tool. Being the recommended monitor for Celery, it obsoletes the
>   Django-Admin monitor, celerymon and the ncurses based monitor.